# get the url of a new page when it is opened after click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, html

I am writing a test that clicks on a button and opens a new tab and directs you to a new website. I want to call in that website value so I may parse it after the rfp code in the webpage name.  I then open a decoder site and use it to decode and be sure the decoded webpage name works properly.

The code I'm using:

```js
this.switchesToGetQuotePage = function() {
  browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles) {
    newWindowHandle = handles[1]; // this is your new window
    browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function() {
      getCurrentUrl.then(function(text) {
        console.log(text);
      });
    });
  });
};
```

When I call the getCurrentUrl function it returns below as the value:

```js
data: ,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the protractor built in `getLocationAbsUrl()` to get the url of the current page if its angular based. Here's how -

```
browser.getLocationAbsUrl().then(function(url){
    console.log(url);
});
```

However if you are working on a non-angular page then do wait until the page loads as the url changes (through redirections) until final page is delivered to the client and then use `getCurrentUrl()` on the page. Here's how -

```
   var ele = $("ELEMENT_ON_NEW_PAGE"); //replace it with your element on the page
   browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function() {
      browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ele), 10000).then(function(){
        getCurrentUrl.then(function(text) {
          console.log(text);
        });
      });
    });
```

Hope it helps.